# Java Melody - Error resolving template "error" when hit the hit URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, java-melody

please help, i have got some issues when hit the URL java melody,

I have configured app with following library :

1. Spring boot 2.0.4.RELEASE
2. spring-security-oauth2 2.3.3.RELEASE
3. spring-security-jwt 1.0.9.RELEASE
4. javamelody-spring-boot-starter 1.74.0

I am following the spring boot and java melody guide via https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki/SpringBootStarter

```
javamelody.init-parameters.monitoring-path=/admin/monitoring
```

This my spring security config,

```
@Override
public void configure(final WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/v1/login/*", "/api/v1/batch/*","/api/v1/*/init*", "/error", "/v2/api-docs",
            "/configuration/ui","/swagger-resources", "/configuration/security", "/webjars/**",
            "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui","/swagger-resources/configuration/security",
            "/swagger-ui.html", "/admin/*", "/*.html", "/favicon.ico", "//*.html", "//*.css", "//*.js",
            "/proxy.jsp", "/api/v1/version");
}
```

and when hit the localhost:8080/admin/monitoring

```
 HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "error", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
 type Exception report

 message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "error", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

 description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

 exception

 org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "error", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.forwardToErrorPage(ErrorPageFilter.java:197)
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.handleException(ErrorPageFilter.java:180)
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:145)
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66)
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:123)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
id.com.tri.bonstri.filter.CorsConfig.doFilter(CorsConfig.java:92)
 root cause

 org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "error", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.resolveTemplate(TemplateManager.java:870)
org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:607)
org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098)
org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072)
org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:354)
org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:187)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1325)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1069)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1008)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.forwardToErrorPage(ErrorPageFilter.java:197)
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.handleException(ErrorPageFilter.java:180)
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:145)
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66)
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:123)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
id.com.tri.bonstri.filter.CorsConfig.doFilter(CorsConfig.java:92)
```

Is any miss configure the Java Melody or Spring Security ?

thank you very much. :)